# Cypress Intercept Maneuvering Interchangeable Response Body Object Name

Tags: cypress

Good day, I'm trying to get a value from a response body that located deep into the object tree.
This is the Cypress code

```
cy.intercept('GET', 'https://api.staging.ethicalstg.com.au/organisations/*').as('search')
        
        cy.wait('@search').its('response.body')
            .then((body) => {
                cy.log(body.data.entities.users)
            })
```

and this is the result log
[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6Xl5.png)

What I want to get is the Id, inside the object named with the same Id I want to get.
The id is changed depending on the account that logged in.

How do I get the Id number??

I've tried changed the log to:

```
cy.log(body.data.entities.users[0])
```

but it return empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Object.values` to convert an object's properties into an array, then use indexing.

```js
const users = body.data.entities.users
const id = Object.values(users)[0].id
```

or if you only want the id, use `Object.keys` because it also happens to be the key of the `users` mapping object.

```js
const users = body.data.entities.users   // mapping object
const id = Object.keys(users)[0]
```